# Compare 3 matrices and count the number of maximal number in each of them

Tags: matlab

There are 3 matrices with the same size `A`,`B`,`C`. Now I want to compare them entry by entry and output 3 numbers which are the number of maximal elements of each of the 3 matrices (ignoring all cases with ties). How should I do that efficiently in Matlab?

Example:

```
A = [1 2 1 2]
B = [2 1 3 1]
C = [3 1 2 3]
```

The 1st entry `C` is biggest, 2nd entry `A` is biggest, 3rd `B`, 4th `C`, so the 3 numbers output are: 1, 1, 2, representing the biggest entry in each of the 3 matrices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>> M = [A;B;C]; % concatenate into a single matrix
>> [~,idx] = max(M); % get index of maximum in each column
>> vals = hist(idx, 1:size(M,1)) % make histogram of results

vals =

     1     1     2
```